# Error in calculate volume of sphere but the formula is correct

Tags: c++, function, formula

I want calculate surface area of sphere and volume of sphere, but the volume of sphere is incorrect. If I input r=3 then V=84.8229980469 instead of V=113.0973358154, though the formula volume of sphere is correct. Please help me. This is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
float surface_area_of_sphere(float r)
{
    float L;
    L=4*3.14159265359*r*r;
    return L;
}

float volume_of_sphere(float r, float &V)
{
    V=4/3*3.14159265359*r*r*r;
}

int main()
{
    float radius,volume,area;
    cout<<"Please input radius of sphere r = ";
    cin>>radius;
    cout<<"==================================="<<endl;
    volume_of_sphere(radius,volume);
    cout<<"Volume of sphere = ";
    printf("%10.10f\n",volume);
    area=surface_area_of_sphere(radius);
    cout<<"Surface area of sphere = ";
    printf("%10.10f",area);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `4/3` divides two `int` literals (`4` and `3`), so gives a result of type `int`.  That occurs with rounding toward zero, so gives a value of `1`.   The fact it is in an expression with floating point values does not change the way the first part of the expression is evaluated.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aganju suggested use:

```
L = 4.0 * 3.14159265359*r*r;
```

and function `volume_of_sphere()` should not return value.

```
void volume_of_sphere(double r, double &V)
{
    V = 4.0 / 3.0 * 3.14159265359*r*r*r;
}
```

Also, for pi = 3.14159265359 resolution, **replace all `float` data-types by `double`**  to get the desired accuracy.

Answer (score 5):

You are using 4 and 3 in your calculations, those are integers, so the math is done with integers. 4/3 = 1 in integer arithmetic.

Use 4.0 and 3.0 in all places, and it will work.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698738/aganju.  The code now is work.